# Вывод кракозябр при запуске electron-rebuild

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

В NodeJS при запуске приложения electron выдало такую ошибку:

```js
Error: The module '\\?\W:\repositories\private-messenger\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\Release\better_sqlite3.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 83. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 99. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).
    at process.func [as dlopen] (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:5:1800)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1199:18)
    at Object.func [as .node] (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:5:1800)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:988:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:829:12)
    at Function.c._load (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:5:13331)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1012:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:94:18)
    at bindings (W:\repositories\private-messenger\node_modules\bindings\bindings.js:112:48)
    at Object.<anonymous> (W:\repositories\private-messenger\node_modules\better-sqlite3\lib\database.js:9:24)
```

[Порывшись в интернете](https://bleepcoder.com/better-sqlite3/391783546/compiling-error-different-node-js-version) нашёл, что нужно использовать **electron-rebuild**, однако вместо вменяемого результата выдаёт это *(Да, делал так, как сказано в посте на том ресурсе)*

[image: Вывод из консоли]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запустите

```
npm install -g windows-build-tools
```

Если не работает, проверьте установлен ли Python 2.7 (не 3) и .NET 4.5.1.

Из папки `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\.windows-build-tools` запустите
runBuildTools_Full.exe. Открываете BuildTools и нажимаете  modify. Выбираете VC++ 2015.3 v14.00(v140) toolset for desktop.

Далее по одной команде за раз:

```
npm install --save better-sqlite3

npm install --save-dev electron-rebuild

node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild -f -w better-sqlite3
```

Comment: Это нормально, что установка остановилась сообщением "Successfully installed Python 2.7" и при этом не завершается?

Comment: Всё так же не работает, компоненты я установил
https://sun9-5.userapi.com/impg/tsUZkiSLlCWbjjMOgUyJowDgChNaVDNJt5vChw/zDqtxdrlqKE.jpg?size=1920x1050&quality=96&sign=1ba174809083858a17de81187eb330cc&type=album

Comment: Команды надо было набрать в терминале. Cygwin или аналоги